# ant build issues

Tags: ant, target

I have a build with multiple interlinked dependencies, Several projects have common dependencies that are currently compiled more than once. I think in Ant we can tell it not to re-build something if its already just done it as part of the same task, can anyone please advise

Answer (score 1):

ant's javac task will only compile if the source files are newer than the target files.  So that should save you some time.

You can also look into [ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy) for a bit more formal dependency management.

Answer (score 0):

Like leonm says, the compiler will do the right thing.  But that won't stop Ant from rebuilding loads of artifacts.  What I'd suggest is:

- where you can, make targets have a defined output.  So a target that builds a jar file from sources can be skipped if those sources haven't been updated since the jar file was built.
- how do you implement this?  use the [uptodate](http://www.catalysoft.com/articles/AntUptodate.html) task to set a property if something is actually up to date.
- I'd suggest that any targets that do checks be prefixed with a hyphen so they can't be run on their own
- And finally, use the 'unless' attribute of the target element to prevent the target running.